# Creating List of Widgets by Mapping to Multiple Keys

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I'm new to flutter. I've searched it around but, I couldn't find a solution that fits to my case.

I want to give 3 parameters to Answer widget values from map and list them separately. Below code runs perfectly, if I remove color from below and also from Answer widget constructor.

```
...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
    return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer, color);
}).toList()
```

I'm adding Answer widget and the map below. How can I map 3 parameters in above statement?

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;
  final Color color;

  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText,this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: color,
        textColor: Colors.white70,
        child: Text(answerText),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
final questions = [
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
        'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'White'],
        'colors': [Colors.black, Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.white]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
        'answers': ['Rabbit', 'Snake', 'Elephant', 'Lion'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'Who\'s your favorite instructor?',
        'answers': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
      },
    ];
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: I cannot compile because I'm not giving a color value to "color" parameter to Answer widget. During compile time I'm facing with this

Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:50:53: Error: The getter 'color' isn't defined for the class '_MyAppState'.
 - '_MyAppState' is from 'package:quizzapp/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'color'.
             return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer, color);

Comment: Can you add a default value to positional argument? Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText, this.color = null)

Comment: If i add Colors.white to color it works. The problem is in here I cannot obtain colors from Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List> type change is solved the problem.

Comment: Please append your original post with the code sample that works!